# Python OpenCV object tracking

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have choose to step in world of computer vision, ML and AI.
So as a start I tried to make tracker partially following tutorial and partially modifying it to my needs using my knowledge which I already have.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFPDNYOz1EM
What am I doing wrong?
I have tried multiple trackers, but it always returns unknown C++ error.

Source code done below:

```
import cv2, imutils
import numpy as np
import threading

BB= None
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
w = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
h = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))


def tracker_def(image,bool):
 global tracker
 global BB
 BB = cv2.selectROI(image, False)
 if BB != None:
  tracker.init(image, BB)
  y = threading.Thread(target=track, args=(imutils.resize(frame, width=720),))
  y.start()

def track(image):
 global BB
 global tracker


 while True:
     
  success, BB = tracker.update(image)
  
  if success:
      
     top_left = (int(BB[0]),int(BB[1]))
     bottom_right = (int(BB[0]+BB[2]),int(BB[1]+BB[3]))
     cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right,(0,255,0),5)
     
  c = cv2.waitKey(1)
  
  if c == 27:
      
    tracker.clear()
    BB=None
 


while True:
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if BB!= None:
        
     subframe = imutils.resize(frame, width=720)
     y = threading.Thread(target=track, args=(subframe,))
     y.start()
    
    space = cv2.waitKey(1)
    
    if space == 115 and BB == None:
       
       x = threading.Thread(target=tracker_def, args=(imutils.resize(frame, width=720),False))
       x.start()

    cv2.imshow('target vision', imutils.resize(frame, width=720))
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if c == 27:

       break
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("Program exited")
exit
```

*Edit Whole error trace is::

```
Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Petr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()   File "C:\Users\Petr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "D:\High size\targetting program.py", line 29, in track
    success, BB = tracker.update(image) Exception in thread cv2Thread-3.: errorTraceback (most recent call last): :   File "C:\Users\Petr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code   self.run()   File "C:\Users\Petr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "D:\High size\targetting program.py", line 29, in track
    success, BB = tracker.update(image) cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

Comment: What is the error? Please, post the full error trace.

Comment: do this without threading. that is the source of your issues. you use the same tracker object from multiple threads. BAD. and fix your indentation. it's atrocious. and check `ret` after `ret, frame = cap.read()`